# How can I add instantiate a global object and attach it to every request on loopback 4?

Tags: node.js, loopback4

I am using loopback 4 and I want to create an object instance when the server starts and share it in the methods of all controllers.
How can I achieve that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Loopback 4 provides functionality to bind key-value pairs which is stored in memory and can be injected anywhere.**

See the below example:

In your application.ts, you can bind key-value pairs that is maintained by loopback and can be injected into your controller.

```
export class User {
  name: string,
  age: number
}

let user = new User()
user.name = "Name"
user.age = 20


this.bind("user").to(user)
```

And then in your controller, you can simply inject the bound value.

```
export class CustomerDetailsController {
  constructor(
    @inject("user") private user: User
  ) { }
```